# Does Declarative Amazon Signatue Version 4 Named Credential Work At All With External Services and Flow

Tags: api, visual-workflow, namedcredentials, external-services, amazon-aws

Can anyone confirm if they have EVER used **declarative** AWS Signature Version 4 as a Named Credential with External Services and Flow in Salesforce for ANY reason? **Not** Apex Classes to set these. A recent comment by Tim Peng of the Salesforce team suggests that the feature has never worked so we have been wasting LOTS of time and $$. If you did get a response, what auth parameter values did you use in your schema?

Currently the best we can get are 403 or 404 response errors. Get successful 200 using Postman. I think issue *might be*:

```
Content-Type/x-amz-json-1.1 **for successful Postman response**
Content-Type/json **Only similar Salesforce option**
```

Unless Salesforce is translating the above behind the scenes when that specific Named Credential is set, this might be problem; however, debug logs do not show enough to confirm. The full schema we are using is here. (Technically in Postman we are setting the Header values in their UI; however since there is no way to do this in Salesforce we have tried different combinations of that in the schema.) Setting the Content-Type in schema creates an error in Salesforce "Content-Type set twice" since SF provides default values if not set in produces section of schema.

```
"produces"
application/x-amz-json-1.1
```

Does not work in SF. We think it might be that this is just being translated to:

```
application/json
```

**Schema**

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
    "description" : "",
        "version": "1.0",
        "title": "",
        "termsOfService": "http://swagger.io/terms/",
        "contact": {
            "name": "HealthDetail Support",
            "url": "https://www.healthdetail.com",
            "email": "support@healthdetail.com"
        },
        "license": {
            "name": "Apache 2.0",
            "url": "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"
        }
    },
    "paths": {
        "/": {
            "post": {
                "summary": "Gets balance",
                "description": "AccountBalance",
"operationId": "GetAccountBalance",
                "produces": [
                    "application/json"
                ],
           "parameters": [
               {
                  **"name": "x-amz-target",
                  "in": "header",
                  "description": "Generated header parameter. Example value ='MTurkRequesterServiceV20170117.GetAccountBalance'",
                  "required": true,
                  "type": "string"
               },
                              {
                  "name": "Content-Type",
                  "in": "header",
                  "description": "Generated header parameter. Example value ='application/x-amz-json-1.1'",
                  "required": true,
                  "type": "string"
                              },
               {**
                  "in": "body",
                  "name": "body",
                  "required": false,
                  "schema": {
                     "type": "string"
                  }
               }
            ],

                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "success",
                        "schema": {
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/statusSuccess"
                        }
                    },
                    "405": {
                        "description": "Invalid input"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "statusSuccess": {
            "required": [
                "AvailableBalance"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "AvailableBalance": {
                    "type": "number",
                    "description": "Balance in account"
                }
            }
                }
    }
}
```